# How can I access a Vault secret using a token created from a policy?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm running Hashicorp Vault v1.1.0 locally in a docker container in developer mode.  I `exec` into the container to use the cli, and I cannot complete a basic proof of concept with a policy and token which allow me to access only one secret.

Below is a transcript of the actions I've taken using v2 of the secrets engine.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
/ # VAULT_TOKEN=myroot vault kv enable-versioning secret/
Success! Tuned the secrets engine at: secret/


/ # VAULT_TOKEN=myroot vault kv put secret/message value=mypassword
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2019-04-11T20:23:25.0149145Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          5

/ # cat p.hcl
path "secret/message" {
     capabilities = ["read"]
}

/ # VAULT_TOKEN=myroot vault policy write message-readonly p.hcl
Success! Uploaded policy: message-readonly

/ # VAULT_TOKEN=myroot vault token create -policy="message-readonly"
Key                  Value
---                  -----
token                s.hZNCq7Q5plwA4XjcGAcsd5tg
token_accessor       vpcxkGMbDBswfJPTGzzfY4he
token_duration       768h
token_renewable      true
token_policies       ["default" "message-readonly"]
identity_policies    []
policies             ["default" "message-readonly"]

/ # VAULT_TOKEN=s.hZNCq7Q5plwA4XjcGAcsd5tg vault kv get secret/message
Error reading secret/data/message: Error making API request.

URL: GET http://127.0.0.1:1234/v1/secret/data/message
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied


/ #
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you craft a policy for version 2 of the KV backend you need to specify the API paths, not the logical paths that "vault kv" uses.  Your policy should look like this:

```
    path "secret/data/message" {
         capabilities = ["read"]
    }
```

There's a bunch of other quirks you need to be aware of when crafting KV2 policies.  See https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2.html for more information.